# Laravel Eleoquent model automatic fields

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i am new to PHP and Laravel, my question is how does this whole thing with eloquent works.

What i mean is when i create a model class and a migration with it, i can just use it like that `Model->title = "value";`. How does eloquent models figure out table structure and create member variables within the class.

```
class Post extends Model
{
  public function author()
  {
    return $this->author;
  }
}
```

Is there some kind of reflection stuff going on with Schemas created in migrations ? or some polymorphic magic ?

Comment: Have you read the appropriate documentation?

Comment: Eloquent understands relationships between tables because you have to tell the Model what relationships they have. In this case, an author has many posts and a post belongs to an author. As explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: @DimitriMostrey i am more interested in a php part of it, What mechanism inside of  it allows me to do `$this->author` without declaring a variable within that class.

Comment: @AntonStafeyev $this in the context of a model is the model itself. `class Post extends Model`. Have a look at the illuminate model class. It's one of the largest and most complex files of the Laravel project. The mechanism behind the expression `$object->var` or `$object->method()->var` you'll find in PHP's native StdClass and Object Oriented Programming (OOP). If you are interested in understanding the mechanism, this is what you'll need to study. The PHP website itself has a good starting point: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: If you are interested in online learning, Bitfumes is an excellent channel. He explains PHP OOP in layman terms here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLe30vg_FG4OSEHH6bRF8FrA7wmoAMUZLv The rest of his channel and playlists are worth a look.

Comment: @AntonStafeyev Thanks for your eloquent response. You asked about the mechanism, how can I know your knowledge of PHP/OOP? If you do, you would have figured it out by now. Here is your answer: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not member variables. Eloquent doesn't know anything about your schema until it actually queries it. So when the model is retrieved from the database, the selected fields are stored in an array called `$attributes`.

There is a magic method for objects named `__get` that is being used here. This is called when you try to access a non accessible property of the object. Since there are no public member variables with the name of the field it calls `__get`. When you look into that method defined on Model you will see it calls `getAttribute`.

Just like there is a `__get` there is a `__set` magic method for setting non accessible properties. On the model `__set` calls `setAttribute`.

I hope this gives you some enlightenment on this subject. There are more things in play like relationships and accessors/mutators but this is the basic idea.

[PHP.net Manual - OOP - Property Overloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) `__get` `__set`

[Laravel Framework Github - `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1627) `__get`

[Laravel Framework Github - `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1639) `__set`

[Laravel Framework Github - `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5a748eecae35fd453e0b1e4d4b6f4fadf0d3e7ac/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L355) `getAttribute`

[Laravel Framework Github - `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5a748eecae35fd453e0b1e4d4b6f4fadf0d3e7ac/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L636) `setAttribute`